# Will my program crash in production when there is only id debug lines for switch case's default block

Tags: ios, swift

Recently when fixing an issue I found the below piece of code and wondering if it will crash in production.  I am not able to replicate any crash in simulator as well as my 5s (iOS 10.0).

```
 switch myVar{
  case 1 : //some code
  case 2 : //some code
  default : 
            #if DEBUG
            print("no match")
            #endif
  }
```

My understanding is that in the release build will not have the if DEBUG lines and so the default will be followed by "}". Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you won't be able to even make a release build. Because when making a release build, all lines in `#if DEBUG ... #endif` are removed.

When compiler removes lines

```
#if DEBUG
print("no match")
#endif
```

it will just throw error that you need at least a break statement in `default:`.

Give it a try and modify your scheme to Release and see what will happen.

Comment: Try to archive it, sign with distribution certificate (or AdHoc certificate) and install it on your device. If it doesn't crash it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

The above piece of code will not crash. The crash may be due to piece of code in case 1, 2. Please do check over there.